# Rotating the gradient

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have a triangle T in 3dimensional space and i want to rotate it in arbitrary ways. The coordinates for T are given by $f: T_R \in \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow T \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ where $T_R$ is a flat reference triangle.
The gradient $\nabla f$ is then given by a $3\times 2$-matrix. How can I compute the gradient of the triangle (from the old gradient) after a rotation (lets say a rotation with angle 30 deg around the z-axis)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute the Jacobian matrix of $f$ after the transformation of coordinates induced by a rotation in $\mathbb R^{3}$. A caveat: a flat reference triangle $T_R$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb R^{2}$; you have to suppose that your given function is at least $C^{1}$ is a suitable open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ containing $T_R$. If this is the case, all you need is the formula for the Jacobian of $f$ after the change of variables induced by a rotation in $\mathbb R^{3}$.

#### References

- [Jacobian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)
- [Effect of transformation on the Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions) (multivariable chain rule)
- [Explicit formula for rotations in $3$ dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions)
- For the rotation you mention, [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) are the right choice:

Comment: thank you @900 sit-ups a day for the nicer formatting

Answer (score 0):

A rotation $Rot$ is a linear function. Then $D(Rot\circ f))=Rot\times Df$.
Here $Rot=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{3}/2&-1/2&0\\1/2&\sqrt{3}/2&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.